# Request input from the View Controller in a Model without breaking MVC in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, model-view-controller

I have an Objective C app and I am trying to follow the MVC guidelines laid out.

There is a point in my Model where user input is required before any further calculations can proceed.

Is there an elegant way I can request input from the controller without breaking MVC?

The only way I can think of doing this right now is just returning a value a nonzero value from the method in the model to the controller, and then having the control call a separate method to send the input to the model.

I was hoping there is some other way to pause the execution of the code in the model while it waits for input from the controller.

Here is some applicable code. I simplified most of it for readability.

Relevant ViewController function:

```
@implementation GameViewController

-(void)tap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    if(gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        id view = gesture.view;
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[GameBoardTileView class]]) {
            GameBoardTileView *gameTileView = (GameBoardTileView *) view;
            int row = gameTileView.row;
            int col = gameTileView.col;
            [self.game chooseTileAtRow:row column:col];

            // Updates states of all game tiles after tapping one tile               

            [self updateTiles];

        }
    }
}

@end
```

Relevant Model function:

```
-(void)chooseTileAtRow:(int)row column:(int)col
{
    // Retrieves the game tile at the spot just selected

    GameBoardTile *tile = [self retrieveTileAtRow:row column:col];

     // Makes sure the spot is empty
    if (tile.companyType == -1) {

        // If no company type is found generate a random company type
        if (!tile.companyType) {
            //NSLog(@"changing company type");

            if ([self.chainsInPlay count]) {

                /////////// Would like index to be given by the Controller instead of randomly generated
                int index = [self generateRandomNumber:0 end:[self.chainsInPlay count]-1];

                tile.companyType = [[self.chainsInPlay objectAtIndex:index] intValue];                        
                [self.chainsInPlay removeObjectAtIndex:index];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What the view controller does is it keeps track of a grid of tiles that when an individual tile is tapped, it sends that row and column over to the Model using `chooseTileAtRow:column:`. The model retrieves a `GameBoardTile` at that row and column and gets the `companyType`. If the `companyType` does not exist (== 0), I would like it to be set. Currently it just generates a random number for testing purposes. Ideally, I would like this number to be passed in from the Controller and selected via user input.

Comment: It would help to see some of the applicable code. that way we can see how you've implemented MVC and give feedback

Comment: I have attached some parts of the code very simplified down. I hope this adds some clarity.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot "pause execution" or "wait"; don't even think that way.

It is perfectly reasonable for the model to have a property `needsMoreInfo` or to return `false` or nil from some data request or other method in order to say that it can't proceed without further information.

The controller could thus *ask* the model whether it needs more info, and supply it, before requesting the real calculation.

Comment: Ok I just wanted to understand if this was common practice or not when coding in MVC. I'll go with my initial instinct and split the method out and return something like a false value.

Comment: Well, I think most people don't maintain as admirably strong a separation between controller and model as you are clearly trying to do! But in one sense this is no different than using, say, a nil placeholder when we have no data yet, which is certainly common.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to split your model's method, so you can call different parts in your VC. It depends on your MVC logic. You can also use NotificationCenter or delegate pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You should most likely be using the delegation pattern.

Essentially, a base class can define itself as a view controller's delegate, while instantiating the view controller. You use a protocol to ensure that the base class implements all the necessary methods. Your view controller can then blindly call methods on the delegate (often passing arguments).